# Delphi component installation using .DCU file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am delphi developer and want to install component for Delphi 7 on Windows XP and 2007. I have .DCU files only.
When I try to install .DCU from Component > insatll packege > Add> select .DCU file then it shows error like "Invalide Package file"

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems off topic. I think you will get better answers on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is the correct site.

Comment: Are these .DCU files specifically compiled for Delphi 7? If they are perhaps compiled for newer version of Delphi you won't be albe to use them since they require different dependancies to other .dcu's that are not available in your Delphi version.

Comment: @Kahil: Sounds like you don't understand the question. It's perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I'm not a Delphi programmer, and maybe misunderstood the question. Just wanted to point Amruta to the site about installing software is discussed, and not down voted. (I figurred s/he has problems installing some software). My bad.

Comment: When I did google for error I get something like .dcu files are version compatible.but am not sure .I have to install that files on Dwelphi 7 but provided .dcu file compiled in Delphi 6. Does it really affect?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong mechanism to install the component. Instead of **Install Packages** you need to select **Install Components**. This will present a dialog which allows you to specify the unit file name that contains the component(s). You get the choice of installing the component into a new package, or an existing package.

Comment: When try to install .dcu from Install component option it shows error like "Line too long". and when click Ok from error message,display file with non readable format. How could we install then?

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons for that. You've not given any version details, or described the steps you took.

Comment: What I did is for delphi 7. But I have no idea in which version of delphi that DCU files created. Does it matter? Can we install .DCU files that compiled in older version of Delphi (5 or 6) on Delphi 7?

Comment: Yes it matters. The .dcu file has to match the Delphi version you use. Why are you using random .dcu files whose provenance you do not know? All this is moving quite far from the original question which I believe that I answered.

Comment: I agree but ,I tried to install that .dcu files on Delphi 6 and Delphi 5 but shows same error.

Comment: Well, perhaps the dcu isn't what you think it. Compile one yourself to prove the feature works. I think there's nothing more to be said at this question.

Comment: I guess you think that component installation using dcu files is done some other way.

Comment: No, It is the only way that I know.

Comment: I cannot imagine what more you are looking for then. Never mind.

Comment: I'm running into this same frusteration.  Installing a component in Delphi should not be so complicated